# How to skip persisting blank values in an ADF table?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 12c and ADF-BC and i am facing the following problem:

I have an `<af:table>` with 5 rows (assume one `<af:inputText>` in each row).

These rows have been initialized manually by inserting them in a method on the Application Module which I invoked before page load.

I want to allow rows - `<af:inputText>` to be empty on submit, but I don't want to persist them in the database.

So if I have filled 2 out of the 5 rows, it must insert only the fulfilled rows on DB.

Is there any efficient way to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the state of the row before committing and you can then remove it based on your requirement

You need to pass a row to the getRowStatus method and based on its state delete if necessary

```
  public String getRowStatus(Row row) {
    JobsViewRowImpl rwImpl = (JobsViewRowImpl)row;
    byte newRowState = rwImpl.getNewRowState();
    String rwStatus = translateStatusToString(rwImpl.getEntity(0).getEntityState());
    return rwStatus;
}

private String translateStatusToString(byte b) {
    String ret = null;
    switch (b) {
    case Entity.STATUS_INITIALIZED:
        {
            ret = "Initialized";
            break;
        }
    case Entity.STATUS_MODIFIED:
        {
            ret = "Modified";
            break;
        }
    case Entity.STATUS_UNMODIFIED:
        {
            ret = "Unmodified";
            break;
        }
    case Entity.STATUS_NEW:
        {
            ret = "New";
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
}
```